# How can I fix ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row?

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE customer (   id_customer NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,   name
   VARCHAR2(10),   surname VARCHAR2(20));
```

CREATE TABLE customer_wer (
  id_customer NUMBER,
  name VARCHAR2(10),
  surname VARCHAR2(20),
  data_from DATE,
  data_to DATE NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT customer_wer_pk PRIMARY KEY (id_customer, data_from),
  CONSTRAINT customer_wer_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_customer)
  REFERENCES customer (id_customer));

`SELECT COUNT(customer.id_customer) 
   FROM customer JOIN customer_wer
     ON customer.id_customer = customer_wer.id_customer
  WHERE (SELECT customer_wer.id_customer 
           FROM customer_wer JOIN customer
             ON customer_wer.id_customer = customer.id_customer
          GROUP BY customer.id_customer) >= 8;`

In 'customer' table there are 5 customer and in 'customer_wer' there are 48 positions. Every customer from 'customer' table has 8 related positions in 'customer_wer' table. I wan to know how many customers have 8 or more related positions in 'customer_wer'. How can I do it using select?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you *want* the query to do?

Comment: I have two tables. One contains just customers, and second contains customers orders. I would like to know how many customers made more than 8 orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `MAX` for instance:

```
SELECT COUNT(customer.id_customer) 
  FROM customer JOIN customer_wer
    ON customer.id_customer = customer_wer.id_customer
 WHERE (SELECT MAX (customer_wer.id_customer) 
          FROM customer_wer JOIN customer
            ON customer_wer.id_customer = customer.id_customer
         GROUP BY customer.id_customer) >= 8;
```

Or - even better if possible - add some conditions to your sub select, so that it returns a unique result.

Another option, if you want to check whether one of the rows returned by the sub query is 8, is to use the `IN` operator:

```
SELECT COUNT(customer.id_customer) 
  FROM customer JOIN customer_wer
    ON customer.id_customer = customer_wer.id_customer
 WHERE 8 IN (SELECT customer_wer.id_customer
               FROM customer_wer JOIN customer
                 ON customer_wer.id_customer = customer.id_customer
              GROUP BY customer.id_customer);
```

or use `EXISTS` to and move the condition `>= 8` into the sub-query:

```
SELECT COUNT(customer.id_customer) 
  FROM customer JOIN customer_wer
    ON customer.id_customer = customer_wer.id_customer
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT customer_wer.id_customer
                 FROM customer_wer JOIN customer
                   ON customer_wer.id_customer = customer.id_customer
                WHERE customer_wer.id_customer >= 8
                GROUP BY customer.id_customer);
```

***p.s.***: (added as per latest comment)

```
SELECT COUNT(c1.id_customer) 
  FROM customer c1
 WHERE 2 <= (SELECT COUNT (cw1.id_customer)
               FROM customer_wer cw1
              WHERE c1.id_customer = cw1.id_customer);
```

Comment: Adding 'MAX' doesn't work. 'Distinct' will not work also. Subquery must return few positions. Question is how I can compare few positions with number "8"? For example, customers has some orders, every customer can have few of them, how can i select only customers with 8 orders?

Comment: Isn't the `IN` operator working? Sounds like it could .... if not: why? If you need `>= 8`, `EXISTS` should be fine

Comment: Both solutions result in 0 and there should be 6 as result.

Comment: Do you mean the whole `SELECT`? You could check the sub query first (take the last statement). If it returns no result there are probably no rows with `customer_wer.id_customer >= 8`.

Comment: Subquery with 'customer_wer.id_customer >= 8' returns no rows.

My subquery 'SELECT COUNT(klient_wer.id_klienta) FROM klient_wer JOIN klient
              ON klient_wer.id_klienta = klient.id_klienta
              GROUP BY klient.id_klienta'

results 6 rows with a value of 8. I need to compare this 6 rows with number '8' in main query and I should have '6' as result.

Comment: In this case, the condition in the query of your question wouldn't be _true_ as well. The sub query returned several results (and this is the reason for the error you got), however, all of the rows in the sub select have a `customer_wer.id_customer` value smaller than `8`

Comment: Ok I think that my question is unclear. Below You can see how I have created tables.

customer (
  id_customer NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  name ,
  surname);
  
customer_wer (
  id_customer,
  name,
  surname,
  data_from DATE,
  data_to DATE NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT customer_wer_pk PRIMARY KEY (id_customer, data_from),
  CONSTRAINT customer_wer_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_customer)
  REFERENCES customer (id_customer));

There are 5 customers in 'customer' table which have 8 related rows (each) in 'customer_wer' table. Now I would like to know how many customer has 8 or more related positions in 'customer_wer'

Comment: Ok, using some data I can see why you are not satisfied ;). What I did above was rather a technical approach - without looking at any results. `MAX` didn't work because of the `GROUP BY` clause - same for `EXISTS`. Once you remove the group, you get either none or all records. `IN` didn't run into error but it returns either all or no records as well. May be you can write which records you want to count. Check this Fiddle as well: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/79d12/1 may be it's already the solution

Comment: Let's use Your example. I want to know how many customers from 'customer' table has 2 or more records in 'customer_wer' table. We should get '2' as result because customers with ids - 1 and 9 have two or more records in 'customer_wer' table. I still don't know how to do this :/.

Comment: Check this one: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/79d12/3. It selects every customer from table `customer` that has more than two occurrences in table `customer_wer`. The occurrences are count in a sub-select and their number is compared in the `WHERE` condition of the main select.